# Confidence interval from covariance matrix

Tags: matrices, statistics, normal-distribution

We have a matrix of stochastic variables $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma^2)$, where $\Sigma^2$ is a positive definite covariance matrix. How do we calculate the 95% confidence interval for X? (lets say that $X$ consists of 5 variables).

Comment: What is x in this case? and isn't 1.645 the quantile for the 90% distribution?

Comment: Yes, what is $x$?  Do you want the confidence interval for the sum $\sum_i x_i$?  And do you want a one-tail or two-tail CI?

Comment: A confidence interval is calculated for an unknown *parameter*. What is the parameter here?

Comment: $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix-not $\Sigma ^2$